# Why is my C# code not breaking correctly?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, n, sum = 0;
        double avg;

        Console.Write("Enter up to 10 numbers \n");
        Console.Write("-------------------\n\n");

        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write("Number {0}:", i);
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            sum += n;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        avg = sum / 10.0;
        Console.Write("Sum: {0} \nAverage: {1}", sum, avg);

        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit..");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The user can input up to 10 numbers, which will return the sum, average, and difference between each number. If the user inputs 0, the code will break and calculate what the user had previously inputted ~ my code is not breaking correctly and I'm at a lost what I'm doing wrong.  :(

Comment: `i` will never equal zero, since it goes from 1 to 10. You probably want `if (n == 0)` instead? As an aside, check out int.TryParse rather than Convert.ToInt32 so bad input won't crash your program. And your average calculation is not going to be accurate if the user enters fewer than 10 numbers.

Comment: Your old code is an excellent practice example of how to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the start of your `for` loop. Create _Watches_ on your `i`, `n` and `sum` variable.  Start stepping.  Move the CMD window that pops up out of the way so you can see stuff in the debugger and in the command window.  Note how the numbers in the command window start at 1 and go up (not zero).  If you step like this in a debugger, the problem should pop out at you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are verifying if(i == 0), i is your iterator and starts at 1, this condition will never be true!

try instead if(n == 0) to stop if user input is 0.

Comment: I realized I made a stupid mistake :/ ~ thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to break when i is 0, instead you should check if n is 0. Something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, n, sum = 0;
        double avg;

        Console.Write("Enter up to 10 numbers \n");
        Console.Write("-------------------\n\n");

        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write("Number {0}:", i);
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            sum += n;

            // Changed the i to n
            if (n == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        avg = sum / 10.0;
        Console.Write("Sum: {0} \nAverage: {1}", sum, avg);

        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit..");
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```